# How to add a new key-value pair in jsonb without creating a new object? (Postgres)

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

i need to add a new key-value pair into existing json object. Will appreciate any help.

json:

```json
{
  "json_col": [
    {
      "val1": 1,
      "val2": 0,
      "val3": "qwe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I came up with this query

```
UPDATE table SET  
json_col = jsonb_set(
    json_col, 
    '{json_col}', json_col->'json_col' || '{"test":123}'))
where id=6400
```

and it will output:

```json
{
  "json_col": [
    {
      "val1": 1,
      "val2": 0,
      "val3": "qwe"
    },
    {
      "test": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

But i need this json to be a single object (without additional brackets), like this:

```json
{
  "json_col": [
    {
      "val1": 1,
      "val2": 0,
      "val3": "qwe",
      "test": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the version of your PostgreSQL server? json_col is an array - whitch element do you want to update ?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis 12.6, yes, that's correct, i want to update object, which is an element in the json_col array

Comment: I ment the array may have several elements in it. Whitch elementent do you want to update then: one specific or all the elements in the array?

Comment: This array have only one element in it, so i want to update only one element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is basicaly correct, you just have to correct `path` value provide for `jsonb_set` and also extract the first element of `json_col` element:

```
UPDATE some_table SET  
  json_col = jsonb_set(
    json_col::jsonb, 
    '{json_col,0}', 
    (json_col->'json_col'->0)||'{"test":123}'
  )::json
where id=6400;
```

you can test it on: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a38ee10a89766c0d73588073b2f9ad35)

**Multiple elements in the array**

If your `json_col` array contains multiple elements and you want to update every one of them with same key:value pair you should use this query instead:

```
UPDATE some_table SET  
  json_col = jsonb_set(
    json_col, 
    '{json_col}', 
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(elem||'{"test":123}') 
       FROM jsonb_array_elements( json_col->'json_col') AS elem ) 
  )
where id=6400;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c7350ab7a3dc2c147737e94f1bfbea84)

Comment: Great, it works, thank you, but i was actually wrong - there can be multiple elements in array, so how should it look in case of multiple elements?

Comment: Actually keys will be same, but values will be different

Comment: If so, you have to join the source of your key values to `jsonb_array_elements( json_col->'json_col') as elem` part and then use jsonb_build_object instead of constant '{"test":123}'.  If you want complete example you should provide all the data needed to build the test case (best in form of SQL statements) and the expected result.